# Run script at shutdown

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, init-script

I have a script that I want to run at startup and on shutdown.

I have placed the file in `/etc/init.d` and named it testscript.sh

Then I changed permissions `sudo chmod 755 testscript.sh`

Then I made link `ln -s /etc/init.d/testscript.sh /etc/rc2.d/S99testscript.sh`

So far so good, now the script runs at startup. I tried doing the same but making the links in rc0.d and rc6.d but that didn't work, the script still won't run at reboot/shutdown.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm running Ubuntu on putty client.

Comment: Try renaming your script to `K99testscript.sh`. `S` stands for *start* scripts, thus they are run when system starts, `K` stands for *kill* scripts, thus they are run when system is shut down. Also I would recommend to create `Systemd` unit files (if you are using new version of Ubuntu) rather than `SysV` scripts.

Comment: That didn't work. I've also noted that the files in rc0.d and rc6.d are shown i red while the linked file in rc2.d are shown is sky blue. Does that have something to do with it? As I understand, the linked files should be shown i sky blue and archived files in red?

Comment: A link showing as red (depending on what kind of red) is generally a broken link (i. e. a link that is not in fact pointing to a file or directory that actually exists).  You can demonstrate this for yourself with `ln -s /nosuchpath ./broken-link; ls -l ./broken-link; rm ./broken-link`.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is not telling people in the question what version of Ubuntu this is.  Ubuntu has not used the `rc` system that you are fiddling with since 2006.  For over a decade [it has only supported what you are playing with using two distinct sets of backwards-compatibility shims.](http://askubuntu.com/a/632969/43344)  If you are new to this stuff, and using an Ubuntu version from the past decade or so, then do not begin with `rc` scripts at all.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2. I have tried putting symlinks in all rc*.d dircetorys but still no startup or shutdown script. I have followed the instructions written by NarunasK. I have do it this way, it's part of a lab assignment.

Comment: If it's a lab assignment then it needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Put your script into the `/etc/init.d` directory.

Set up executable bit: `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/your_script.sh`

Check what's your `runlevel`:

```
# runlevel
N 5
```

Create `S`tart symlink in the appropriate runlevel dir. (5):

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/your_script.sh /etc/rc5.d/Syour_script.sh
```

Create `K`ill symlink in the shutdown runlevel dir. (0):

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/your_script.sh /etc/rc0.d/Kyour_script.sh
```

To do it properly read [here](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts).

Comment: If I remember correctly,  the program `update-rc.d` was used for ubuntu to create those symlinks for SysVinit.